# Enter key Pressed in textBox to trigger opening of Form2

Tags: c#, textbox

So I have this in FormOne:

```
private void input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData.Equals(Keys.Enter))
    {
        x = 5;
        string customStreamer = textBox1.Text;
        Form2 twitchTV = new Form2(this);
        twitchTV.Show();
    }
}
```

and this in FormTwo:

```
switch (formOne.x)
{
    case 5:
        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/widgets/live_facebook_embed_player.swf?channel=" + formOne.customStreamer;
        break;
}
```

But when I debug the program and type in a streamer username and press Enter, Form2 does not open up. I tried adding breakpoints and it seems like it doesn't even reach the input_KeyDown method. What is the problem and how would I be doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is the input_KeyDown method isn't wired up to the textbox you are pressing Enter in. Especially since your breakpoint isn't hit. Otherwise your code looks like it will work and in a quick test project I made, does work. So check to make sure your textbox has a KeyDown event handler of input_KeyDown.

Comment: Thank you Dave! But now when I click enter it opens up Form2 with the Shockwave Flash Object, but it goes to: axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/widgets/live_facebook_embed_player.swf?channel=" + formOne.customStreamer; without actually adding customStreamer

Comment: Rob G's answer actually contains the reason for that where he talks about the local scope of customStreamer.

Answer (score 0):

customStreamer is declared as a variable in local scope, not in the formOne class where it would need to be to be referenced from outside after the event handler has finished executing.

Additionally you need to assign a Form1 variable called 'formOne' with the parameter you passed in, which I'm sure you're doing but just making sure.

Finally, make sure you have attached your EventHandler properly to the correct textbox, either through the designer or in your initialization code.

Comment: Ugh, sorry I just started learning C# a few days ago. But what do I change to customStreamer if it's declared as a variable in local scope?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring customStreamer as a variable in the event of input_KeyDown.
Remove the string datatype declaration and it should work.
Like this:

```
private void input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData.Equals(Keys.Enter))
        {
            x = 5;
            customStreamer = textBox1.Text;
            Form2 twitchTV = new Form2(this);
            twitchTV.Show();
            label1.Text = customStreamer;
        }
    }
```